# Sum of string values of a list in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sum

I am having trouble deriving the overall sum of string values.
While I am able to generate the following if there are in integers form:

```
size = {
    'serverA' : [10, 10],
    'serverB' : [3, 3, 3],
}
```

If I used `sums = {k: sum(i for i in v if isinstance(i, int)) for k, v in size.items()}`, I will be able to get output such as `{'serverA': 20, 'serverB': 9}`

However, instead of having integers in the values of the list, I got string as follows:

```
size = {
    'serverA' : ['10', '10'],
    'serverB' : ['3', '3', '3'],
}
```

And if I used the same command to generate the sum of values, while there are no errors, the sums are clearly wrong in which the output is `{'serverA': 0, 'serverB': 0}`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `map()` to map the values to `int`s:

```
>>> {k: sum(map(int, v)) for k, v in size.items()}
{'serverA': 20, 'serverB': 9}
```

Note: if you have values that aren't integers this will raise a `ValueError` exception.
Don't really understand why you had the `isintance(i, int)` in your base case.

Comment: Can't beat this ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `int(integer_string)`

```
sums = {k: sum(int(i) for i in v) for k, v in size.items()}
```

Also, keep in mind using `isinstance` is typically considered an antipattern. If you want type checking check out [Python 3.6 type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) or use a different language.